# Smalot PDF Parser not working with preg_match_all

Tags: php, string, pdf, pdfparser

Im using https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser and its getText() method to parse a page of a PDF file that contains text (not image of text), but then when i try to apply a regex to this text it doesnt work.

Ive echoed the var containing the extracted text and everything seems ok, ive copied the text shown in the browser and stored it in a var but when i compare this new var to the one containing the original text they're not identical. Any leads?

```
$parser = new Parser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile($pdfFile);
$pages = $pdf->getPages();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $fullPageText = $page->getText();
  echo $fullPageText; 
  echo gettype($fullPageText); //Prints string

  $copiedTextFromFullPageTextEcho = "...";
  echo $fullPageText === $copiedTextFromFullPageTextEcho ? "Yes" : "No"; //Prints No
  preg_match_all("/CANT\.\s+\S+\s+(.+?)\/.+\/(.+)-(.+)\s+(\d+)(\s+TOT AIS)?/", $fullPageText, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  print_r($matches); //Prints Array ()
}
```

Comment: You're asking two questions: 1. Why are the texts not the same? 2. Why doesn't my regex not work? It's better to concentrate on one question. For Q1 it would be nice to know in what way the two text differ, and for Q2 it would be nice to know how it doesn't work. Just saying they are difference and it doesn't work, doesn't give us much information. Remember, we cannot run your code, because we don't have your PDF and there's no guarantee that another PDF would show the same problems. We also don't know what your regex is supposed to do. Please add the information in your question.

Comment: *"Any leads?"* Echo the [`bin2hex()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) of both strings to find out the differences. There may be a non-breaking space or something like that.

Comment: In case you do have non-breaking spaces, just add the `u` modifier to your pattern to make it UTF-8 aware.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in which encoding PDFParser returns the page text and faced the same problem today.
Indeed the string returned by PDFParser will be different from what you print and copy from your browser or text file.

What helped me - is to replace multiple spaces in the PDFParser output:
$page = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $page);
and then push this $page variable to preg_match